# How to get an ESRB rating for my game?

Tags: content-rating, esrb

What does it take to get an ESRB rating for my game?

Comment: I know that this is not exactly a correct reply, but I think that this information would be usefull. If the ERSB rating is too expensive, you can try the TIGRS rating. http://www.tigrs.org/

Comment: One thing to consider here is, why do you want an ESRB rating in the first place? If you're selling your game online, just let people know on your website about the intended audience and objectionable content; if you're honest, that should be good enough for most customers.

ESRB ratings are only useful for retail stores, which generally won't take your game anyway unless you have a publisher (and if you do, the publisher will probably handle ESRB for you).

Comment: It was more of a general wondering than anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary point of entry appears to be the [ESRB's website](https://www.esrb.org/publishers/). The process appears to be that you need to make a physical letter on corporate letterhead with all sorts of information proving you are a real business. You then need to send them the letter and wait 5 days at which point they will send you a user/password for their website, at which point you can request a rating, which will take time and some amount of money.

Comment: http://www.esrb.org/ratings/ratings_process.jsp

Comment: So it's both inconvenient and costly?

Comment: Of course. How else can you keep the government away than by adding our own bureaucracy?

Answer (score 8):

For anyone looking at this in 2020, the International Age Rating Coalition (IARC) website gives you the info you need.
If you have a digital copy game, and  submit your game to a place like the Google Play Store or Nintendo eShop, you will fill out the IARC questionnaire. A game rating will immediately be assigned 100% free of charge for all regions where your content is available. **It does not cost money. I repeat, you do not pay the IARC, ESRB, PEGI, etc, for anything.** The only thing that costs money is development licenses which are issued by the digital storefronts, and not by the IARC, ESRB, PEGI, etc.

- [International Age Rating Coalition (IARC)](https://www.globalratings.com/)
- [ESRB](https://esrb.org/)

Comment: Welcome to GDSE & thanks for contributing an up to date answer to an older question!

Comment: No problem. Thought I'd help out best I could! Thanks for the edit on there.